# Searching for PDF Not working in Nexus?

Tags: android, file-search

```
    public void check4PDF(File dir) {
    String pdfPattern = ".pdf";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                check4PDF(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)) {
                    FileDetails mFileDetails = new FileDetails();
                    mFileDetails.setmFilename(listFile[i].getName());
                    mFileDetails.setmPath(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    pdfDetails.add(mFileDetails);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code does not give any result in nexus.

```
if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState)
            && !Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(storageState)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SD Card not found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ScanSDCardTask temp = new ScanSDCardTask(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getActivity());
        temp.execute(".pdf");
    }
```

I think it is the problem with the path please help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging  your code ? Do you get the list of files even?

Comment: it is giving the pdfDetails.size() as 0. phone memory contains pdf files.

Comment: @AshwinSAshok insted of writting your own code for checking files..use default file searching code..it is fast and efficient too..

Comment: default file searching code..can specify..?

Comment: @AshwinSAshok posted my code..check like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in this way..it is fast and efficient than your searching file..

```
private void checkForPdf(File file) {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            File[] listFiles = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    return filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
                }
            });
            for (File file2 : listFiles) {
                //here you will get all pdf files..
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for you help..but its also giving same result. i mentioned that its working correctly on other devices. getting this error on google nexus.